# How to validate a Email Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I already have a code, but it's not successfully working. No popup happens when I press submit. Thanks for the assistance in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Email Validation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Email </td>
<td> <input type = 'text' name = 'email' size = '30'  />
</td>
</tr>
  </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "ValidateEmail()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not a dupe of that - they have the code, they're just having trouble doing something with it

Comment: @zevee the question was edited post close vote. However, it needs to be closed as a typo, as it's simply missing the `()` on the method call `ValidateEmail`

Comment: It would be better to ad an event listener, but a simple set of parenthesis will indeed solve the problem.

Comment: It's not working, even with the () function. How can you close a duplicate that's simply not working?

Comment: The duplicate gives me a different code, that's not helping me learn. I rather used my own code I constructed

Comment: I got it, thanks everyone!

Comment: Your email is required to have 2 to 3 character top level domain. It no more works in the modern world!

Comment: Please investigate your case further. Whether it's due to the regexp mismatch? If yes, please show us sample EMails those don't satify the expression. Check whether ValidateEmail is called. And then simplify your code into some minimalistic example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick="ValidateEmail()"` inside of your tag - remember you have to call the function